# How to emerge different versions , ebuilds of php

Tags: linux, php, gentoo

I'm trying to compile  a lower version of php (5.2) as gentoo is selecting 5.3 and i'm having some coding issues with the new version

nano /etc/portage/package.use

=dev-lang/php-5.2.14 ~amd64

still when I emerge emerge -av php

is stil selecting version 5.3 which is by default

how else can I force emerge to select the version I want

ls /usr/portage/dev-lang/php/
ChangeLog            php-5.2.14.ebuild    php-5.3.4.ebuild
Manifest             php-5.2.16.ebuild    php-5.3.5.ebuild
files/               php-5.2.17.ebuild
metadata.xml         php-5.3.3-r1.ebuild

Answer (score 1):

You should find the old ebuild package, it should be in portage directory.

Then, if I remember correctly, the comand to run was "ebuild old-package.ebuild" and it will compile it.

Answer (score 0):

didn't emerge spit an error notification immediately? keyword specifications are supposed to go into /etc/portage/package.keywords.

@comment:

```
emerge -av =php-5.2.17
```

if any of them are keyworded, then:

```
echo "=dev-lang/php-5.2.17 ~amd64" >> /etc/portage/package.keywords
```

Comment: yes sorry about that, they are in keywords..

Comment: emerge doesn't display any error, no

Answer (score 0):

First, php 5.2.17 already has `amd64` in its keywords so `~amd64` would do nothing.

Second, it is almost never a good idea to attempt to mix `~amd64` and `amd64` That is why you set `ACCEPT_KEYWORDS=~amd64` (or `amd64`) in `/etc/make.conf`. It is a per-host variable.

Third, you should use `/etc/portage/package.mask` like so:

```
>dev-lang/php-5.2.17
```

This will prevent all ebuilds with version greater than 5.2.17 to be masked.

Then run `emerge -upv --deep --newuse php`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP versions are now slotted in Gentoo, so you can have easily either version, or even both at the same time on system and switch between them with eselect. There is a [complete guide](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/php/php-upgrading.xml) on the Gentoo home page on how to correctly migrate to slotted PHP versions.